# Call flutter widgets dynamically by their name (with a string)?

Tags: string, flutter, dynamic, widget

I have several custom widgets which alle accept the same data type as a parameter:

```
class Widget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget1({@required this.data});
  final data;
}

class Widget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget2({@required this.data});
  final data;
}

...
```

I have another widget which acts like a widget manager:

```
class WidgetManager extends StatelessWidget {
  final data;
  final type;

  WidgetManager({this.data, this.type});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (this.type == 'Widget1') {
      return Widget1(data: this.data);
    } elseif (this.type == 'Widget2') {
      return Widget2(data: this.data);
    } 
  }
}
```

In PHP I could call the widgets with a string like this:

```
$widget_name = 'Widget1';
$widget = new $widget_name($data);
```

Is there any way to do a similar thing in flutter?
Like `return this.type(data: this.data);`?

Comment: Call  WidgetManager({this.data, this.type}) from another widget

Comment: Thank you. Imagine that I have 1000 custom widgets. Instead of using 1000 `if`-statements I would like to simply call the widget by their name, like `return this.type(data: this.data);`

Comment: This is not possible. What you are doing is the correct solution